# Is it possible to track where I am in an array with array_walk_recursive?

Tags: php, recursion, multidimensional-array

Let's say you have an array like this:

```
array
(
    ['one'] => array (
                      ['wantedkey'] => 5
                      ['otherkey1'] => 6
                      ['otherkey2'] => 7
                     )
    ['two'] =>  => array (
                      ['otherkey1'] => 5
                      ['otherkey2'] => 6
                      ['wantedkey'] => 7
                     )
    ['three'] =>  => array (
                      ['otherkey1'] => 5
                      ['wantedkey'] => 6
                      ['otherkey2'] => 7
                     )
)
```

---

If you apply sth like this to the array you get all instances of 'wantedkey':

```
function test_print($item, $key) {
  if ($key === 'wantedkey') {
    print $item;
  }
}

array_walk_recursive($myarray, 'test_print');
```

But array_walk_recursive doesn't tell me (afaik) where I am in the array....is there any way to track the position where 'wantedkey' has been found in the example above with array_walk_recursive?

Any hint is highly appreciated, thanks in advance! :-)
I know this has been asked before but I'm wondering if anyone has found a solution yet...

Comment: so you would like to know 'one'=>'wantedkey'=>5 ?? or 'one'=>0=>5, 0=>0=>5 ?? I can't tell if it is the previous indexes or the 'if it was numeric' index that interests you

Comment: as stilstanding said i need to track element position as well as the hierarchy, i guess this is not possible with array_walk_rekursive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [RecursiveArrayIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php) if you need to track element position and hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

You know exactly where you are in the array at any given time, by virtue of the recursive definition.  Since you have to provide a smaller and smaller array on each successive call, you can see exactly where you are based on the size of the array.

Comment: This seems correct technically speaking, but actually I'm looking for outputs that tell me where 'wantedkey' has been found in one,two and three in a way that I can access the other values at the concrete position, e.g. otherkey2=>7 in three.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, RecursiveArrayIterator is working exactly as expected :-)
A working example can be found here:
[link Tree recursion](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread303349.html)